# Why does my blender keep crashing?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I am editing images with video editor and I have just gotten a image cropped and sized when it crashes. I thought it was my ram so I lowered it down to 4500. my actual ram is 7.9GB. I add a image then I put a color behind it (while the image in from has image offset on and overdrop) then I expand the color and it crashes. every time no matter what image. I will be happy to explain further if you might have a clue but I have not included the information. I am using this for a school project so I really need to get bender to work.

Comment: Could you provide an example blend file? Or describe the single steps that will reproduce the error for you? Though this might be a bug which should be reported to the official bug tracker...